# CSS: Stacking Order Issue

Tags: html, css

I currently have a few vertical tabs that when hovered expand down toward the content within the page. As they expand down, a "content" div within the hovered tab expands out to the right away from the tab. I like the way this looks aside from the fact that I can't seem to get the "content" div to appear on top of the other tabs. I would assume that this is due to stacking order since when I reverse the order it works just fine. Can anyone help me resolve this issue? I've tried z-index, and opacity tricks to get it to work and nothing so far. I understand that z-index changes context based on position and opacity but my knowledge on this is limited. When you supply a possible solution, can you explain why it works?

Code:

```css
.tab {
  background: #0AF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}
.tab:hover {
  top: -5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;
}
.content .foot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.tab:hover > .content, .content:hover {
  left: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.about {
  background: #0AF;
}

.social {
  left: 80px;
  background: #F05;
}
.projects {
  left: 150px;
  background: #0F5;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab about">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">About Me</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab social">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">Social Media</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab projects">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">Projects</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give an `z-index` to `.tab:hover`. The order is given by the order of elements in the DOM so if you give a z-index you create a new stacking order referred to the nearest position relative parent. Smashing magazing has a good post in merit [link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)

```css
.tab {
  background: #0AF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
  
}
.tab:hover {
  top: -5px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;
}
.content .foot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.tab:hover > .content, .content:hover {
  left: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
}
.about {
  background: #0AF;
}
.social {
  left: 70px;
  background: #F05;
}
.projects {
  left: 130px;
  background: #0F5;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab about">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">About Me</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab social">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">Social Media</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab projects">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">Projects</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out, it made me realize that the content class is being used as a child of the tab class thus making the z-index irrelevant to the other tabs.

Answer (score 0):

> Just Insert `z-index:999` to `.content`

```css
.tab {
  background: #0AF;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}
.tab:hover {
  top: -5px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
}
.content {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #EEE;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
  opacity: 0;
  text-align: center;
  color: #222;
  z-index: 999;
}
.content .foot {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.tab:hover > .content, .content:hover {
  left: 40px;
  width: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
}

.about {
  background: #0AF;
}

.social {
  left: 80px;
  background: #F05;
}
.projects {
  left: 150px;
  background: #0F5;
}
```

```html
<div class="tab about">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">About Me</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab social">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">Social Media</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="tab projects">
  <div class="content">
    <span class="foot">Projects</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why would you add a z-index of 999? itacode's answer of assigning the z-index in tab:hover worked like a charm with a value of 1. It made me realize that the "content" div is a child of the hovered tab, so even if it has a z-index of 1 and the tabs have 0, the tabs still show up.

Comment: @lxxtacoxxl,  What is the difference? content must show up all Elements so better is have maximum z-index.

Comment: @lxxtacoxxl, when you hover tab,must content cover Everything that is right side ,May Elements be in right side that have z-index,so i use 999 to make sure it work well.